# Using Neyman pearson lemma when ratio comes out to be zero.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

Consider a Bernoulli random variable:

$$X_i=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{with probability }p \\
0, & \text{with probability }1-p
\end{cases}$$

You observe the outcomes of two Bernoulli trials and want to test $H_o : p=0$ against $H_1 : p=0.5$. Use Neyman-Pearson lemma to determine the most powerful test of $H_o$ versus $H_1$. What are the Type 1 $(\alpha)$ and Type 2 $(\beta)$ errors for your test?

**Here's how I tried. Please point out my mistakes and correct me:**

$$f(x_i)=
\begin{cases}
(1-p)^{1-x_i}  p^{x_i},  & x_i =0,1 \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}  \\
\end{cases}$$

$H_o: p=p'=0$

$H_1: p=p''=0.5$

$\frac {L(p')}{L(p'')}$= $\frac {0}{1/4}$ = $0 \le k$ where $k$ is a positive number.

$\implies \frac {L(p')}{L(p'')} \lt k$   (for all $k \gt 0)$  $\implies \frac {L(p')}{L(p'')} \lt k$ for all $X_i$s (here for $X_1$ and $X_2$)

So here my critical region is all values of $X_i$ i.e., $X_i=0,1$ or to say $[X_1=0,1$ and $X_2=0,1]$

$\alpha = P_{H_o}(X_1=0,1$ and $X_2=0,1) = 0$

$\beta =1- P_{H_1}(X_1=0,1$ and $X_2=0,1)$

But, $P_{H_1}(X_1=0,1$ and $X_2=0,1)$

$=P_{H_1}(X_1=0,X_2=0) + P_{H_1}(X_1=0,X_2=1) + P_{H_1}(X_1=1,X_2=0) + P_{H_1}(X_1=1,X_2=1)$

$=(\frac12)(\frac12)4 =1$

So, $\beta = 1-1=0$

But both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ cant be zero? 
someone please tell me how to apply neyman pearson in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{L(p')}{L(p'')}
= \begin{cases}
\frac{0}{1/4} & \text{if }X_1=X_2=1, \\[10pt]
\frac{0}{1/4} & \text{if }X_1=1\ \&\ X_2=0, \\[10pt]
\frac{0}{1/4} & \text{if }X_1=0\ \&\ X_2=1, \\[10pt]
\frac{1}{1/4} & \text{if }X_1=X_2=0.
\end{cases}
$$
The probability of a false positive (Type I error, falsely rejecting $H_0$) is $0$, since $X_1+X_2$ cannot be positive if $p=0$.  But the probability of failing to reject $H_0$ if the alternative is true is $1/4$, since $\Pr(X_1=X_2=0\mid p=0.5)=1/4$.

Comment: taking $p=0$,,,, when $x_i = 1$ then clearly $f(x_i)=1^0 0^1=0$.
BUT when $x_i = 0$ then  $f(x_i=0)=1^1 0^0=??$

Comment: There's no point in including that case, since when $p=0$, that won't happen.

Comment: ok. got it. But please tell me how to find $\alpha$ (type 1 error). This is the definition of $\alpha$ which I know: It is the probability that $X_i$s fall in critical region assuming null hypothesis case. So please tell me, how did you find critical region (and also $\alpha$)

Comment: Please tell me how are we getting the critical region in this case when in the ratio of $\frac{L(p')}{L(p'')}$ there are no $X_i$s??

Comment: The critical region is $X_1+X_2\ge1$, since it is only in that case that one could reasonably reject $H_0$.

Comment: I am still not able to get how Neyman pearson lemma told you that critical region. Even after solving so many questions on Neyman Pearson my doubt is still the same , what to do if the ratio i.e., $\frac{L(p')}{L(p'')}$ comes out to be zero (or some other constant number )?? Also shouldnt  Type 2 error in this case  be $3/4$ (if critical region is $X_1 + X_2 \ge 1$) and NOT $1/4$??

Comment: It's not the Neyman-Pearson lemma that tells us what the critical region is; it's the fact that you reject $H_0$ iff the likelihood ratio is on one side of a boundary that tells you what the critical region is. The Neyman-Pearson lemma only tells you that this test is more powerful than any other.

Comment: ok it means I can reject $H_o$ if Likelihood ratio $= 0 \lt k \implies X_1 + X_2 \ge 1$? But what about the condition when Likelihood Ratio $ = \frac{1}{1/4} = 4 \lt k$ (4th condition)?? what to do then?

Comment: At least tell me, are you sure that you calculated Type 2 error $(\beta )$ right? I think you calculated $\gamma$ instead.
$1-\beta = \gamma$